# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Home'

Tags: python, django

I worked with Django Framework
So i have this files:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(blank = timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Menu(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    position = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext

from models import Post, Menu

def index(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.order_by('-published_date')
    menu_items = Menu.objects.order_by('position')
    context = {'post_list' : post_list, 'menu_items' : menu_items }
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)

def post(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk = post_id)
    menu_items = Menu.objects.order_by('position')
    context = {'post' : post, 'menu_items' : menu_items }
    return render(request, 'blog/post.html', context)
```

Recently i've tryied to add a Category models like:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
        fields
```

and in Post models i've added something like that:

```
category = models.ForeignKey('Categories')
```

I forget to use the default command and when i try to makemigrations they asked me to put a value or something like that.. I've wrote 'Home' and after that when i try to migrate the manage.py i've got the following error: http://puu.sh/k0BLh/0dd2da2657.png

I've deleted Categories model and the category field from Post and again, when i try to migrate the manage.py i've got the same error but the site works (runserver).. how to solve this?

I want to have a table Categories and when i add a new Post i want to have a field to chose the category from Categories..

Comment: Will you be more specific about the fields in `Categories` class?

Comment: name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

Comment: Did you add `category` field after some entries in `name` fields?

Comment: No...................

Comment: then just try migration again and give value `None` if it ask..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try migration again and provide `None` value.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are just python files. You could either fix incorrect migration, or just remove it and run `makemigrations` command again. This [documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/writing-migrations/) explains the structure of migration file.